# Unable to remove page from primary menu

Tags: menus, pages, navigation, headers

A new page based on a default template always appears on the website primary navigation, however i is not included in the primary menu on the backend. Anyone knows what could be causing this and how to prevent it (as I don't want this page to be visible on the primary menu).
Thank you all in advance for your time and attention.

Comment: Hi. Have you enabled the `Automatically add new top-level pages to this menu` option in `Apperance > Menus`?

Comment: Hi Jack, no that option is disabled

Comment: Your theme may be using something like `wp_list_pages()` instead of an actual editable menu. I would check around in the theme files to verify. Usually this sort of thing is stored in `header.php` though depending on the theme it may be elsewhere. Viewing on the front end and using a right-click, "inspect element" can help you determine what code is wrapped around your menu, then from there, you can do a search for that within your theme. Feel free to update your question with `header.php` or whatever file contains it for more help.

Comment: Hi WebElaine, thank you but in the end I managed to find the issue: when calling the main menu I simply called it as primary menu but not by it's name (Main Menu), therefore any changes I made to it were simply ignored and directly applied to the primary settings.
But thank you very much for taking the time to respond WebElaine.
PS: how could I close the question? Dos this not work like StackOverflow?